# How do you unlock the events A Beery Good Wedding and Knowledge for Thirst?

Tags: fiz

I have completed every other challenge except for unlocking two of the hidden employees.  What do I have to do to trigger the events that allow for Frank Cuccinello and Prof. Zymurgis to be unlocked?

Answer (score 1):

These are random events. If you keep playing, you'll eventually get them.